# EXPECT script, how to handle multiple pages of output

Tags: linux, expect

I am having an expect script to put in a file a list with all the mac-addresses associated to a switch.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn telnet 192.168.20.222
match_max 10000
expect "*?to continue*"
send -- "\r"
send -- "show mac \r"
expect -- "*?2626#*"
send -- "exit \r"
expect -- "*?2626>*"
send -- "exit \r"
expect "*?y/n*"
send -- "y \r"
```

it all works fine but if there are too many address the switch will say someting like this:

> -- MORE --, next page: Space, next line: Enter, quit: Control-C

of course there can be N pages, with N beeing unknown.
How should i do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
send -- "show mac \r"
expect {
    "MORE --, next page" {send -- " "; exp_continue}
    "*?2626#*" {send -- "exit \r"}
}
```